# NPM doesn't recognize semvers that end with '*-rc' (i.e. release candidates); causes dependencies to fail to resolve. What's the usual workaround?

Tags: node.js, npm, react-native, semantic-versioning

Here's a really simple example to illustrate the problem.

I'm trying to use `react-native@0.8-rc` together with `react-native-linear-gradient`.

`react-native-linear-gradient` defines `react-native@>=0.4.4` as a peer dependency. Fair enough.

I run `npm install`.

I get an error saying that

`react-native@0.8-rc` does not satisfy `react-native@>=0.4.4`.

This issue makes `npm` useless, because it's getting in the way of developers and package maintainers. See [here for an example](https://github.com/lelandrichardson/react-native-parallax-view/issues/15).

How does anybody using node do any useful work with release candidates?!?! What is the workaround?

---

For your reference, the error coming from NPM 3.1.2 (the latest version at the time of writing), looks like this:

```
MyProject@0.0.1 /path/to/MyProject
├─┬ react-native@0.8.0-rc
│ └── stacktrace-parser@0.1.1  (git://github.com/frantic/stacktrace-parser.git#493c5e5638a79b4d5886171867a06275cc703b00)
└─┬ react-native-linear-gradient@0.3.2 
  └── UNMET PEER DEPENDENCY react-native@>= 0.4.4

npm WARN EPEERINVALID react-native-linear-gradient@0.3.2 requires a peer of react-native@>= 0.4.4 but none was installed.
```

Comment: Okay, the workaround is simply to fork the repository, update the `peerDependency` to include the release candidate version, and then point `package.json` at the fork (e.g. `    "react-native-linear-gradient": "fatuhoku/react-native-linear-gradient",
`). 

This pattern can be applied to Cocoapods too.

Comment: I think it's their fault for using an invalid semver, it should be `react-native@0.8.0-rc`. edit: [maybe not](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/tree/v0.8.0-rc)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

OK, so I looked at this and as far as I can tell it's a bug with the version of `semver`.

Short term: I would suggest forking the `semver` repository, fixing the bug in your fork, then just referencing your `semver` fork in `package.json` for you project.

Long term: submit a bug report with your specific issue, or submit a code fix for it yourself and request to be a contributor.

Comment: Yep thanks figured I had to do that.  I almost thought there might have been a way to tell npm to ignore versions requirements haha. Imagine that.

Answer (score 0):

Point NPM at the github release:

```
npm install --save https://github.com/facebook/react-native/archive/v0.8.0-rc.tar.gz
```

Edit: Sorry, nevermind, i misread and thought you had problems installing it. i dont see a way around it other than modifying the peerDependency